# Isotope Not Sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope v1.5.24 and jQuery in no-conflict mode, and trying to sort the data by a number but it is not working.

I've set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tgelles/esxw3kne/1/, and you can see the first item should be third in the list.

The isotope code is:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    //set isotope variables
    var $container = $j('.section-container');
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        getSortData: {
            course_number: function ($elem) {
                return parseInt($elem.find('.course-number').text(), 10);
            }
        },
        itemSelector: 'section',
        layoutMode: 'straightDown'
    });
    $container.isotope({
        sortBy: 'course_number'
    });
```

FWIW the 'course_number' sortBy is actually json decoded from an API, which in the fiddle is simple HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `parseInt` on a string such as this: `'AS.010.232'`  According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `parseInt` will return `NaN` for such values.  Quoting from there:

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

Since all of those sort values are being interpreted as `NaN` it may actually be sorting them, just in some random order.

Instead of calling `parseInt`, try just returning the text directly:

```
getSortData: {
    course_number: function ($elem) {
        return $elem.find('.course-number').text();
    }
},
```

This seems to be working in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esxw3kne/2/), and is also pretty much identical to the examples on Isotope's manual entry for [sorting](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/sorting.html).

Comment: Thanks so much!

However, when I attempt this code on a live site, it still does not work. For example: [link](http://krieger.jhu.edu/phbeta/undergraduate/courses/)

Comment: Looking at the DOM for that page, I don't see any content at all in the `isotope` container

Comment: put differently, for all I know it is sorting, it's just sorting 'nothing'.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. When I'm logged in to WordPress Admin I can see it, but not incognito..

Anyway, here's an updated jfiddle with production scripts and styles: http://jsfiddle.net/tgelles/4y4gv34b/

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be, though it could be an issue with your markup, (after a cursory glance it seems to be valid to me). I'm not sure why it would work in my fiddle and not in yours.  Try taking some of the other features out one by one until it either works or you've taken everything else out.

Comment: Got it! There were conflicting isotope classes in the css that was causing the numbers to render out of order. It's now working: [jsfiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/tgelles/4y4gv34b/4/

(Now, to figure out why it's not appearing online. If you query string on the end of the url, does that render anything?)

Comment: no, still not seeing anything on that page, tried adding an empty query string (?) with no change. (what query string would you like me to try?)